# Error in implementing OAuth2 for Swagger Documentation of an API

Tags: rest, api, swagger

I have the following code in:

```
/oauth2/gARD:
get:
  tags:
    - RM API
  summary: Fecthes as per user's request.
  operationId: gARD
  security: 
    - OAuth2: [read]
  consumes:
    - application/json
  produces:
    - application/json
  parameters:
    - in: header
      name: token
      description: Authorization
      type: string
      required: true
  responses:
    '200':
      description: Successful 
    '500':
      description: Returns error message
```

And I have the following in the components category below the above code:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
      OAuth2:
         type: oauth2
         flow:
         authorizationCode:
            authorizationUrl: https://example.com/oauth/authorize
            tokenUrl: https://example.com/oauth/token
            scopes:
               read: Grants read access
               write: Grants write access
               admin: Grants access to admin operations
```

Everything's referenced from [this link.](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/) I am getting "Security requirements must match a security definition" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing OpenAPI 2.0 and 3.0 syntax. `components.securitySchemes` is OpenAPI 3.0 syntax, but your path definition uses 2.0 syntax.

Assuming you use OpenAPI 2.0, the security definition should look like:

```yaml
securityDefinitions:
  OAuth2:
    type: oauth2
    flow: accessCode
    authorizationUrl: https://example.com/oauth/authorize
    tokenUrl: https://example.com/oauth/token
    scopes:
      read: Grants read access
      write: Grants write access
      admin: Grants access to admin operations
```

Comment: It worked. One more question I have i.e. if I want to add more permissions with read in the array beside OAuth2, what should I do? Example: [read, write]

Comment: @S.P: yes, exactly that.